# Spotfire - calculating % variance in the Grand Total column

Tags: spotfire

I have created a cross-table with 3 rows of data

Last Year
This Year
% Variance (Custom Expression) = (Last - This) / Last

This has 4 columns - Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 for a given year.

When I add the Grand Total via properties / Totals - it correctly displays the totals for Last Year and This Year, but instead of calculating the % Variance based on the Grand Total it sums the % variance for Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4. I have tried changing the Calculate Totals to "on underlying row values" and "as the sum of cell values" but neither produce the correct results.

Am I missing something, or setting up the Cross Table incorrectly?  How can I have a Custom Expression display in the Grand Total?

Thanks,
Grant

Comment: can you post an image of this?

Comment: thanks - this has now been resolved.  I found that some underlying data was not aggregating as it should, and whilst I had accounted for this by using a AVG calculation in part of the Custom Expression, this messed up the Grand Total calculation.  Changing the aggregation of the data to allow for SUM to be used within the Custom Expression has fixed the issue.